# takeWhile, dropWhile laziness java9

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, java-stream, java-9

In scala those methods works fine but in java9 dropWhile works differently I think.

Here is example for takeWhile

```
Stream.of("a", "b", "c", "de", "f", "g", "h")
                .peek(System.out::println)
                .takeWhile(s -> s.length() <= 1)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output is fine:
a, b, c, de, [a, b, c]
It does not process elements after "de" so it works as expected

But dropWhile works in different way that I expect:

```
Stream.of("a", "b", "c", "de", "f", "g", "h")
                .peek(s -> System.out.print(s + ", "))
                .dropWhile(s -> s.length() <= 1)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output is:
a, b, c, de, f, g, h, [de, f, g, h]

So it's not stopping after "de" element, it's processing whole collection.

Why is it processing whole collection? I know, that it's needed to take all elements and collect it to the List but shouldn't it stop processing after "de" element?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems, there is a fundamental misunderstanding about how `peek` works. It is not associated with the next subsequently chained operation, like `dropWhile`, but the entire Stream pipeline behind it. And it does not make a distinction between “processing elements” and “take all elements”.

So the simple code

```
Stream.of("a", "b", "c", "de", "f", "g", "h")
      .peek(System.out::println)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

“takes all elements”, but prints them as they are passed from the Stream source to the Collector.

In your example, it makes no difference, whether an element is passed to the predicate of `dropWhile` or directly to the `Collector`, in either case, it will be reported by the `peek` operation placed before *both*.

If you use

```
Stream.of("a", "b", "c", "de", "f", "g", "h")
      .dropWhile(s -> {
          System.out.println("dropWhile: "+s);
          return s.length() <= 1;
      })
      .peek(s -> System.out.println("collecting "+s))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

instead, it will print

```
dropWhile: a
dropWhile: b
dropWhile: c
dropWhile: de
collecting de
collecting f
collecting g
collecting h
```

showing how the evaluation of `dropWhile`’s predicate stops after the first unaccepted element whereas the transfer to the `Collector` starts with that element.

This differs from the `takeWhile` where *both*, the predicate evaluation and the collector, stop consuming elements, so there is no consumer left and the entire Stream pipeline can stop iterating the source.

Answer (score 6):

This is expected behaviour and identical to how it works in scala, dropWhile processes the entire stream.

dropWhile is the reverse of takeWhile.  takeWhile stops processing when the condition becomes false.  dropWhile handles the entire stream, but only does not pass on any elements while the condition is true.  Once the condition becomes false dropWhile passes on all of the remaining elements regardless of whether the condition is true or false.

Answer (score 4):

I'm probably going to state the obvious here, but it makes sense for me, so might help you as well.

**takeWhile** takes the first n elements until the Predicate is hit (it returns true). So if you have let's say 7 elements in your incoming stream and takeWhile will return true for the first 3, then the resulting stream will contain 3 elements.

You can think about it like this:

```
Stream result = Stream.empty();
while(predicate.apply(streamElement)){ // takeWhile predicate
   result.add(streamElement);
   streamElement = next(); // move to the next element
}
return result;
```

**dropWhile** says drop the elements until the Predicate is hit(it returns true). So after dropping your 3 elements, what will your result stream look like? To know that we need to iterate all other elements, that is why peek reports the rest.

I also like the analogy to dropWhile from a Set (as opposed to a List). Suppose this is your set :

```
 Set<String> mySet = Set.of("A", "B", "CC", "D");
```

And yo will do a dropWhile here with the same predicate (because it's not a List and you do not have encounter order); after the dropWhile operation there is no way to know the result unless you iterate all elements that where left.

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

Always have a look at the entire stream, particularly the terminal operation to judge how the pipeline behaves. It is `collect` that influences the printed elements as much as `takeWhile` or `dropWhile`.

### In Detail

I'm not sure whether you disagree with the output or the resulting list. In any case it is neither `takeWhile` nor `dropWhile` that is processing the stream but the terminal operation, `collect` in this case. It has the task to collect all elements in the stream and hence "pulls" elements through it until the stream reports to contain no more elements.

This is the case with `takeWhile` once the condition becomes `false` for the first time. After it reports that no more elements remain, collect stops pulling elements and hence the procession of the input stream stops and so do the messages from `peek`.

It is different with `dropWhile`, though. On the first request to it, it "fasts forward" through the input stream until the condition becomes `false` for the first time (this makes `peek` print `a, b, c, de`. The first element that any operation after it sees is `de`. From then on `collect` continues to pull element through the stream until it is reported empty, which is the case once the input stream ended with `h`, which leads to the rest of the output from `peek`.

Try it out with the following, which should result in `a, b, c, de [de]`. (I'm so sure, I didn't even try. ;) )

```
Stream.of("a", "b", "c", "de", "f", "g", "h")
                .peek(s -> System.out.print(s + ", "))
                .dropWhile(s -> s.length() <= 1)
                .findFirst();
```